# how to keep the data as filtered and sorted from angular ui-grid and export it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm using angular ui-grid for large set's of data, now i'm able to export the filtered result's from all paginations,when i apply the sort functionality along with it, it works on the view but not on the imported file, that is the user again needs to sort it after the download using excel(which isn't convenient).

my code

```
function exportFilteredData() {
            $scope.exportDatalist = _.filter($scope.gridApi.grid.rows, (o) => {
                return o.visible;
            });
            var entities = _.map($scope.exportDatalist, 'entity');
            alasql.promise('SELECT * INTO XLSX("Log_Details.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [entities]);
        }
```

NB: Extra dependencies i have used

1. xlsx.js
2. underscore.js
3. alasql.js

Comment: Not sure here, never noticed this one. I see you already made it to https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/1972, so good effort.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for looking.